# Convert edges array on a vector

Tags: julia

I have a graph `g`and I want to convert its edge list in a vector.

For example, If I do:

`collect(edges(g))=`

The result is
`Edge 1=>2 Edge 1=>3 Edge 2=>3`

I would like to have a function such that:

`f(g)= [[1,2];[1,3];[2,3]]`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer**:

Say `edgelist = collect(edges(g))`. Then, `[[src(e), dst(e)] for e in edgelist]` will give you the result as an ordinary array of arrays, like you want.

*Edit*: Or `Tuple.(edges(g))` to get an array of tuples instead, like @BogumiłKamiński mentions in the comment.

**Explanation**:

```
julia> g = Graph([0 1 0
                  1 0 1
                  0 1 0])
{3, 2} undirected simple Int64 graph

julia> edgelist = collect(edges(g))
2-element Vector{Graphs.SimpleGraphs.SimpleEdge{Int64}}:
 Edge 1 => 2
 Edge 2 => 3
```

We can see that the result of `collect(edges(g))` is a `Vector{Graphs.SimpleGraphs.SimpleEdge{Int64}}` (or some similar Vector of some type of Edge, depending on your graph).

Now we want to extract the starting and ending nodes of each of these edges, as simple numbers. If we typed `edgelist[1].` and pressed Tab, we'll see that each Edge has `src` and `dst` as its fields. We could directly use them, but it's usually better to use documented method calls if they're available, instead of internal fields.

Let's check what methods we have available to work on these Edges:

```
julia> methodswith(Graphs.SimpleGraphs.SimpleEdge)

julia> methodswith(Graphs.SimpleGraphs.SimpleEdge, supertypes=true)
...
[9] dst(e::Graphs.SimpleGraphs.AbstractSimpleEdge) in Graphs.SimpleGraphs at /home/Sundar/.julia/packages/Graphs/Mih78/src/SimpleGraphs/simpleedge.jl:20
[10] dst(e::AbstractEdge) in Graphs at /home/Sundar/.julia/packages/Graphs/Mih78/src/interface.jl:84
...
[16] src(e::Graphs.SimpleGraphs.AbstractSimpleEdge) in Graphs.SimpleGraphs at /home/Sundar/.julia/packages/Graphs/Mih78/src/SimpleGraphs/simpleedge.jl:19
[17] src(e::AbstractEdge) in Graphs at /home/Sundar/.julia/packages/Graphs/Mih78/src/interface.jl:65
```

A plain `methodswith` didn't return anything, but when we check for methods that accept `SimpleEdge`s supertypes (which means they'll get called for `SimpleEdge` arguments too), we see that there are `src` and `dst` methods to properly access the source and destination fields of the Edge.

With this information, we can loop through the list of edges with a comprehension, and make a 2-element array of source-destination pairs like you wanted.

```
julia> [[src(e), dst(e)] for e in edgelist]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]
 [2, 3]
```

Comment: A very good explanation. I would just add that most of the time (unless you have a very specific need to have mutable elements) it is not recommended to do such a conversion. Vector of vectors will use up more memory and will be slower to work with than vector of edges. That is why in my initial answer I have not performed such conversion. If you really need to transform edge to something else, it is better to use `Tuple.(edges(p)))` and get a vector of immutable tuples.

Comment: I agree. Make sure that you've explored the methods available for the `Edge` type (like with `methodswith` above), and see how those can fit your needs, before reaching for a conversion to a more familiar type.